# Atomically storing a value in a uint8_t (C)

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc, atomic, memory-model

Let's assume we have a C structure that contains a uint8_t field:

```
typedef struct foo_s {
  uint8_t field;
  // other fields...
} foo_t;
```

If we want to atomically store a value in `field` using a particular memory order, what are the possibilities within the C language? From what I researched

- The [C11 standard](http://web.cs.dal.ca/~vlado/pl/C_Standard_2011-n1570.pdf) does not allow atomic stores (`atomic_store_explicit`) in non-atomic integer types. On top of that, there is no atomic integer type in the standard that is guaranteed to have a width of one byte.
- Another possibility (within C11) is to use a memory fence (`atomic_thread_fence`) and then store the value in `field`. But the standard requires this store to be atomic for the fence to work as intended, so we go back to the issue described in the previous item.

So the solution to our problem *seems* to be out of the C standard...is there any commonly used mechanism for atomically storing a byte?

Please note that we cannot change the type of `field`, since it belongs to a third-party library.

Comment: Is a mutex an option or does the third-party library read from the field without locking?

Comment: @delnan ideally, there will be no locking. Producers will atomically store the value and consumers will atomically load it.

Comment: But locking is possible? Because it really looks like that's the only workable solution (there is almost certainly a complicated algorithm which doesn't explicitly use locks but effectively re-implements a spinlock or some other primitive tool, but that's even less desirable). AFAIK there's not even hardware support for atomic 8 bit writes.

Comment: @delnan Locking is not possible. With respect to the HW support, the SW atomic store operation might be based on atomic 4-byte HW stores and use compare-and-swap to only modify the first byte (see answer from Doug Currie).

Comment: I assume the object of the exercise is to write stuff to the other items in the struct, and then set 'field' to signal completion... which, if 'field' were atomic, would be a store-release.  The problem appears to be **no way** to ensure that writing to 'field' happens after the writes to other items :-(  I do wonder if `atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_seq_cst)` is of any help here ?   [If the documentation for atomics were written with the programmer in mind, the world would be a better place, IMHO.]

Comment: please see the answer to my own question - the 'Related' column on the right hinted at GCC providing atomic byte storages, which are adequate for the problem described

Answer (score 0):

In GCC, the atomic store asked for can be achieved using `__atomic_store_n`, which is included in the Atomics extension and does work at the level of granularity of a byte. The GCC [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) for atomic builtins states that "GCC allows any integral scalar or pointer type that is 1, 2, 4, or 8 bytes in length". A peek at the [implementation](https://github.com/mirrors/gcc/blob/master/libatomic/store_n.c) reveals that the HW store works at 4-byte granularity, but the SW will emulate byte stores by using compare and swap operations (i.e., making sure that concurrent modifications to any other byte in the word are not lost).

My understanding is that the atomic modification works in any integer variable such as `field`- there is no need to change its type or modifiers.

Answer (score -1):

It is not portable, due to endianess and perhaps alignment concerns, but you could alias another union structure to the `foo_t` structure. The alias union structure would have an atomic-sized field that overlaps the entire `uint8_t field`. Now you can update the overlapping field atomically. Since it overlaps the field, that will also be updated atomically.

By alias union structure I mean

```
typedef union alias_foo_u
{
    foo_t orig_foo;
    struct alias_foo_s
    {
        atomic_t field_overlap;
        ...
    } alias_foo;
} alias_foo_t;
```

Comment: This would also overwrite some adjacent fields, which may or may not work.

Comment: Sure, you have to read-modify-write the whole overlapping field.

Comment: @DougCurrie: while your solution would work, it seems overcomplicated: after all, we just want to set a byte! I will accept it if nobody proposes a simpler solution.

Comment: Since that's undefined according to the c standard I'm not exactly sure what we win here - replacing one undefined solution with another?

Comment: @DougCurrie: please see the answer to my own question - the 'Related' column on the right hinted at GCC providing atomic byte storages, which are adequate for the problem described